# Is the winform 'size' property localizable in any way?

Tags: winforms, localization

I'm in the process of writing a set of documents to help other developers in our office localize various components of a large application. I'm using a tool called Globalizer.NET to do the donkey work and it's very good as it even lets you localize the size and position properties of controls to allow for the likely changes in length of text strings once translated. However, it occurred to me that in some cases I might need to re-size the entire form a bit, but Globalizer doesn't let you do this, and I cannot see any other way of doing this. I have even tried manually adding an entry in the language specific resource file for the form size but it doesn't make any difference.

Ultimately, once it has become a little more established, we'd consider moving to WPF which I understand makes this easier, but for now we can't for a number of reasons.

Is there any way at all to localize this property of a winform? I am beginning to suspect not, but figured I'd ask in case someone else has come up with a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry - about a moment after posting this I had a bit of a Homer moment and realised I was trying to use the wrong property - ClientSize is a perfectly localizable property!

Thanks for reading.

Steve